# PHP file unable to read folder content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a web page where students will be able to fill their data correctly and download their result in PDF. An HTML page, a JavaScript file and a PHP file will be used for this. The PDF files are already created and placed in a folder with all the script files. The javascript file is working correctly, it is taking data from all input and generating a filename from it, which is the name of the pre-created PDF file. PHP is unable to read the name of the PDF file stored in the folder and is giving a file not found error.
Please guide me. Thanks

hereis script.js

```
function downloadResult() {
  // Get values from the form and trim any extra spaces
  const registrationNumber = document.getElementById('registrationNumber').value.trim();
  const classId = document.getElementById('classId').value.trim();
  const city = document.getElementById('city').value.trim();
  const dob = document.getElementById('dob').value.trim();

  // Check if any field is empty
  if (!registrationNumber || !classId || !city || !dob) {
    alert('Please fill in all fields.');
    return;
  }

  // Create the PDF file name
  const fileName = `${registrationNumber}${classId}${city}${dob}.pdf`;

  // Create a link element
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = `download.php?file=${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;
  link.target = '_blank';

  // Trigger a click on the link to start the download
  link.click();
}
```

here is php code

```
<?php

// Get the file name from the query parameter
$fileName = $_GET['file'];

// Path to the directory containing PDF files
$directory = 'pdfs/';

// Full path to the PDF file
$filePath = $directory . $fileName;

// Check if the file exists
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    // Set appropriate headers for the file download
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));

    // Output the PDF file content
    readfile($filePath);
} else {
    // File not found
    echo 'File not found.';
}
?>
```

I think this forum will help me a lot and solve my problem.

Comment: While testing, you might want to try echoing or logging the `$filePath`, to see if it's what you expect. You might also want to add some server-side validation, because anyone can bypass the javascript and try the file path directly

Comment: Do some basic [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) to identify whether PHP receives the correct filename, or goes to the correct path on the disk

Comment: It is possibly an encoding-related issue as @aynber advised to log the $filePath and see if there is a difference. Also, test with a new PDF file renamed with a clear name (No special characters or symbols).

Comment: Maybe it is a permission problem. Can www-data "read" the formerly created pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to decode the URI because, in the JS code, you've encoded the URI and tried to fetch the URI in a variable in PHP **$filename = $_GET['file'];**.

Print the **$filename** variable and check, whether the expected URI is being printed or not, if not then decode the URI after this variable **$filename = $_GET['file'];**.

**Try:**

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$decodedFileName = urldecode($encodedFileName);
```

Then echo/print this line to verify the expected file/pdf name. Like this:

```
echo $decodedFileName;
```

**OR**

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$escapedEncodedFileName = json_encode($filename);
$javascriptCode = "<script>
           var encodedFileName = $escapedEncodedFileName;
           var decodedFileName = decodeURIComponent(encodedFileName);
           console.log(decodedFileName);
        </script>";
echo $javascriptCode;
```

I hope this helps or maybe it will somehow help you to debug and then solve the issue which is occurring.

Comment: thanks to all , problem solved,   only a single  JAVASCRIPT  file and DONE!